# why does keypress doesn't return results in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

My code should display results from the API but does not ?Any help will be appreciated.

```
 $("#search").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 10){
    var searchTerm1 = $("#search").val();

    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchTerm1 +"&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
         // console.log(data);
         for(var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
          $("#output").prepend("<div><div class='well'><a href="+data[3][i]+"><h2>" + data[1][i]+ "</h2>" + "<p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></a></div></div>");            
         }
      }

      });
   }
})
```

and the HTML Code:

```
 <form id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
</form>
```

Comment: because you cannot capture unprintable keys like tab and enter with a keypress. You have to use a keydown.

Comment: by the way async :false is going to piss people off. You should never do that unless there is an absolute need. People do not like having their browsers locked up waiting for a response.

Comment: and there is never ever a valid reason to use `async :false` ... in fact it is deprecated